# Rails application not freeing memory?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memprof, oink, objectspace

In my rails application total object are increasing with every request. Objects are not freeing after GC runs. I am using Rails 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3.

Can someone point me in right direction ? Where to start?

What are the available tools ?

Tools which I tried.
ObjectSpace is not referencing a line where these objects created.
Memprof is not working with ruby 1.9.3.
Oink is not referencing a line where these objects created.

Comment: Ruby, like any good GC, wants to minimize the dynamic memory allocations and deallocations. That means that Ruby will allocate a lot of memory once, and keep that memory around for new objects so that there doesn't have to be as many context switches or dynamic allocations. Ruby will only release memory when memory is tight.

Comment: Maybe this comment should be an answer?

Comment: @krunalshah How do you know that GC ran the corresponding resquest/response cycle perhap GC only runs if the memory reach above a threshold unless you manuall invoke `GC` using `GC.start` in your code which too bad

Answer (score 0):

[perftools.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb) has the ability to mention what methods create how many objects:

> CPUPROFILE_OBJECTS=1
>
> Profile object allocations instead of cpu/wall time. Each sample
>   represents one object created inside that function.

However, that's profiling all objects, not merely un-garbage-collected objects. Also, it [segfaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947829/debugging-a-ruby-segfault) on me some of the time.